# SSO login for Apache dolphinscheduler

Tags: single-sign-on, apache-dolphinscheduler

I have set up the apache dolphinscheduler of version 3.1.7 in the system.I am trying to set up SSO login for Dolphinscheduler.
I had configured the api-server as below:

```
security:
  authentication:
    type: CASDOOR_SSO

casdoor:
  endpoint: xxxx
  client-id: xxxx
  client-secret: xxxx
  certificate: xxxx
  #organization-name: built-in
  #application-name: app-built-in
  redirect-url: xxxx
```

But I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.Authenticator]: Factory method 'authenticator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.AuthenticationType.CASDOOR_SSO
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.AuthenticationType.CASDOOR_SSO
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.AuthenticationType.valueOf(AuthenticationType.java:25)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.SecurityConfig.setAuthenticationType(SecurityConfig.java:55)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.SecurityConfig.authenticator(SecurityConfig.java:60)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c0ddea9.CGLIB$authenticator$0(<generated>)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c0ddea9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$101da4f3.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c0ddea9.authenticator(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Is Apache DolphinScheduler compatible with OAuth2 or OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocols? If so, are there any specific properties that need to be enabled for their support?